# "Бабушка надвое сказала" — почему надвое?

Tags: фразеология

Есть выражение "бабушка надвое сказала", в смысле, все это слухи, неточно. А что значит "надвое", почему?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я добавлю.
В гаданиях, пасьянсах часто используется четкая альтернатива: да - нет, сойдется - не сойдется, любит - не любит... Более того, часто случается, что карты мечутся (метаются?) на две стороны (как и в некоторых карточных играх типа фараона). Поэтому - именно надвое, а не скажем "натрое".

Answer (score 6):

Слово "надвое" означает - 1. На две части 2. Двусмысленно, неопределенно, с возможностью двоякого исхода (Толковый словарь Д. Н. Ушакова, 1935-1940).

Так что слово употреблено в прямом значении -"двусмысленно".
Выражение пошло от русских пословиц (указаны к слову "надвое" в Толковом словаре живого великорусского языка В.И. Даля (1863-1866 гг.)) - "Бабушка гадала, да надвое сказала", "Баба ворожила, надвое положила", "Бабушка надвое сказала: либо дождь, либо снег, либо будет, либо нет".

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае "бабушка", "бабка" - это не степень родства и не возраст человека, а, если можно так выразиться, "профессия". "Бабка", в принципе, могла быть и молодой женщиной. "Бабками" называли акушерок - "повитух" ("повивальная бабка"), вообще лекарок, а также гадалок; часто эти профессии совмещались. До сих пор говорят "сходить к бабке" или "ходить по бабкам" - значит: в безвыходной ситуации обратиться к травнице или к гадалке. Часто гадалка отвечала на вопросы верно - потому что, как правило, знала и "клиента", и связанные с ним (с ней) обстоятельства, или же, в силу своего житейского опыта и знания людской психологии, знала, как обычно кончаются те или иные дела. Но если гадалке задать прямой вопрос, ответа на который она не знает, то она, чтобы не подвергать опасности свою "профессиональную" репутацию, начинала говорить двусмысленности, чтобы её слова можно было истолковать и так, и этак. Так, один известный юродивый (не "бабка", а "дедка", но сути это не меняет), не зная ответа на вопрос, всегда изрекал: "Без працы не бенды кололацы", что в переводе с ужасно исковерканного польского языка означает всего лишь: "Без труда не будет калача". То есть по-русски - "Без труда не вытянешь и рыбку из пруда". Таким образом, если ты получил желаемый результат - значит, хорошо постарался, а если не получил - надо было лучше стараться. Смысла в таких предсказаниях нет никакого.